# Use custom templates in posts (not pages)

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

Is there a way to allow the user to select a template for a post in the same way you can select one for a page?

I could create a new post type and create a single.php file for that type, but there are several templates to add I it would mean when I am pulling in posts, I would have to add those post types to the feed throughout the site, so I would like to avoid it if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can use the same process as for page templates by creating your single file with this header at the top of the file:

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: Featured Article
 * Template Post Type: post, page, product
 */
  
 get_header();  ?>
```

Then on the dashboard, you will be able to select the template for your post.

[image]